# How to use folders in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I'm just starting with Codeigniter. I created a simple controller called home.php and a view called home_view.php. This is working fine. Now I would eventually like this site I'm building to have a admin section in addition to the public www version. So I reorganized my file structure like so:

```
controllers:

www
 - home.php
admin

Views:

www
 - home_view.php
admin
```

Eventually I will put the admin related controllers and views in their respective directories. But after having moved my files like so, they no longer work. I think I need to changes something in the routes or config file. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the views you just need to add the folder name to the begin of the view like:

```
$this->load->view('www/home_view.php');
```

You will probably need to redo the routing for the controllers, so that extra folders are accounted for. This can be done with something like the following:

```
$route['admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1/$2';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1/index';
```

This will use the controller($1) and function($2) inside the admin folder if the url is www.example.com/index.php/admin/[controller]/[function]

for the controllers in the admin folder;

and update the default controller like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "www/home";
```

Comment: thanks, worked great. I had to use www.example.com/index.php/admin/[controller]/[function]

Comment: sorry about that, if you do a rewrite of the urls you can get rid of the index.php, there are plenty of tutorials on how to do it